# Centos7 curl and wget always timeout

Tags: firewall, centos7

Centos7, when I run curl and wget, it's always return Connection timed out but I can ping the target url.

Please help.

Sincerely
Bom

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: I disabled firewalld and iptable but I still get timeout.

Comment: Firewalls can be on the source, the target and anywhere in between. Since you are providing absolutely no information about the systems involved it is not possible to give better advice.

Comment: Gerald Schneider thank you for your help
The below is my connection
[root@my02 bommac]# wget google.com
--2020-02-04 15:02:59--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 74.125.200.100, 74.125.200.102, 74.125.200.139, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|74.125.200.100|:80... failed: Connection timed out.